# Custom zoom control in React Leaflet

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm trying to code my own zoom control buttons on my react-leaflet map. I couldn't find any tutorial online so I am trying to figure it out myself but am getting the following error:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
> of a function component. This could happen for one of the following
> reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug
>    and fix this problem.

I've tried various combinations of the below code but get the same error. If anyone can help me out with the code or point me in the direction of a tutorial that does a similar thing that would be great.

```
    const MyMapControls = (event) => {
      const map = useMap();
      if(event==="plus") {
        map.zoomIn();
      }
      if(event==="minus") {
        map.zoomOut();
      }
    }
    const MapComponent = () => {
    if(newActive === "plus") {
                newActive = false;
                MyMapControls("zoom");
            }
            if(newActive === "minus") {
                newActive = false;
                MyMapControls("minus");
            }
    }
/* return map component code goes here */
```

Comment: When you use `useMap` hook inside a functional comp it should be placed as react-leaflet `MapContainer`'s child. You cannot call it like `MyMapControls("zoom");` Please provide the rest of the component code or create a small demo to reproduce the issue

Comment: I've added similar code to a child of the MapComponent and now the buttons work correctly. Would be interesting to see how to achieve this while not inside the child component.